# How to retrieve all wordpress posts (specific type) inside a function in php?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have a function as shown below defined inside **chapters.php** file. In the function below, I am trying to retrieve all wordpress post having type **sdft-episodes**.

**=>**  **chapters.php**:

```
namespace SDFT\Chapters;

function get_down_latest_videos( $post_id ) {  

 $query = new WP_Query(array(
 'post_type' => 'sdft-episodes',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 ));

 while ($query->have_posts()) {
 $query->the_post();
 $post_id = get_the_ID();
 }   
}
```

I want to call this function in a different file. The file name where I want to call the above function is **down-latest-videos.php**.

**=>**  **down-latest-videos.php**:

Here is the complete path and code inside **down-latest-videos.php**:

```
$latest_four_vods = \SDFT\Chapters\get_down_latest_videos( $post_id );

print_r($latest_four_vods);  // Line A
```

The above code is inside the file **down-latest-videos.php**. Line A above doesn't print anything.

**Problem Statement :**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the function above so that when it is called anywhere it should show all the wordpress post having type `sdft-episodes`.

Line A should print should print all wordpress post having type `sdft-episodes`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're namespacing the class that is declaring the function, within `chapters.php` - `namespace absf/Chapters`

Within `down-latest-videos.php`:

```
use function absf\Chapters\get_down_latest_videos; // This pulls in the function from chapters.php

$latest_four_vids = get_down_latest_videos( $post_id );
```

Your function `get_down_latest_videos` is expecting one argument to be passed - `$post_id`.

You're passing it two - `$curated_posts` and `$program_ids`.

Since you're filtering the posts within the `WP_Query`, you don't need to pass in a `$post_id` or any arguments, unless you're using those in the function itself to add to the filter. Currently you're not using `$post_id` anywhere within the function.